# Creating summary report from a matrix in R using vectorization

Tags: r, matrix, vectorization, summarize

I want to create a summary table from a matrix. In the summary table, the first column has bins and subsequent columns are populated with frequencies based on certain conditions and width of bins. I have managed to do this using a `for` loop that traverses each row of the summary table. However, I was wondering whether there is a way to do this without `for` loop or `apply` function because the matrix has a large number of rows.

For example, 'model' has the matrix which I want to summarize in the 'output' table.

```
n <- 1000
set.seed(12)
model <- matrix(0,nrow = n, ncol = 3)
model[,1] <- rbinom(n,1,0.6)
model[,2] <- runif(n,0,120)
model[,3] <- runif(n,70,110)

# Creating summary table of model
output <- matrix(0,13,3)

output[,1] <- seq(from = 0, to = 120, by=10)
for (i in 1:length(output[,1])){
  output[i,2] <- sum(model[,2]>=10*(i-1) & model[,2]<10*i & model[,1]==1 & model[,3]<=100)
  output[i,3] <- sum(model[,2]>=10*(i-1) & model[,2]<10*i & model[,1]==0 & model[,3]<=100)
}
head(output)
```

The output would be:

```
> head(output)
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    0   33   22
[2,]   10   41   26
[3,]   20   28   23
[4,]   30   41   30
[5,]   40   41   25
[6,]   50   43   23
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You are already vectorizing across the rows of `model` so the loop over `output` is probably not very time-consuming. Just for comparison here is an approach using `sapply`:

```
i <- seq(from = 0, to = 120, by = 10)
results <- function(i) {
    cbind(sum(model[, 2] >= i & model[, 2] < (i + 10) & model[, 1] == 1 & model[, 3] <= 100),
    sum(model[, 2] >= i & model[, 2] < (i + 10) & model[, 1] == 0 & model[, 3] <= 100))
}
output <- unname(cbind(i, t(sapply(i, results))))
head(output)
#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]    0   33   22
# [2,]   10   41   26
# [3,]   20   28   23
# [4,]   30   41   30
# [5,]   40   41   25
# [6,]   50   43   23
```

Comment: Thank you so much. The run time is not an issue for one iteration of the model, but it increased significantly when the width of the bin was reduced. Also, I have to run this model a large number of times (up to 100,000), so I was wondering whether further vectorization was possible to reduce the total run time.